# Response / Request pattern ... How to shape the DTOs?

Tags: c#

I am using Request/Response pattern on a service layer. I have, for example:

```
public class FindPostsByTypeRequest : Request {
  public PostType Type { get; set; }
}

public class FindPostsByTypeResponse : Response {
  public IList<PostDto> Posts { get; set; }

  public class PostDto {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
  }
}
```

To handle this request I have an handler:

```
public class FindPostsByTypeHandler : Handler<FindPostsByTypeRequest, FindPostsByTypeResponse> {

  private IContext _context;

  public FindPostsByTypeHandler(IContext context) {
    _context = context;
  }

  public FindPostsByTypeResponse Handle(FindPostsByTypeRequest request) {

    IList<FindPostsByTypeRequest.PostDto> posts = _context.Posts
     .Where(x => x.Type == request.Type)
     .Select(x => new FindPostsByTypeRequest.PostDto {
       Id = x.Id,
       Title = x.Title,
       Text = x.Text
     }).ToList();

     return new FindPostsByTypeResponse { Posts = posts };

  }

}
```

Then I have a dispatcher and use it as follows:

```
FindPostsByTypeRequest request = new FindPostsByTypeRequest { Type = type };

FindPostsByTypeResponse response = _dispatcher.Send<FindPostsByTypeResponse>(request);
```

**The Problem I am trying to solve**:

When I look for posts by type sometimes I need the tags ... Sometimes I don't.
Of course I could always get the tags into my DTOs and use it or not ...
But loading something that I do not need should be avoided ...

So basically I need to get the Posts by Type and "tell" the handler what data do I need.

My idea would be something like:

```
_dispatcher.Send<FindPostsByTypeResponse<PostWithTagsModel>>(request);
```

Where PostWithTagsModel would be the DTO I would need. Then in my Handler I would have:

```
public class FindPostsByTypeHandler : Handler<FindPostsByTypeRequest, FindPostsByTypeResponse> {

  private IContext _context;

  public FindPostsByTypeHandler(IContext context) {
    _context = context;
  }

  public FindPostsByTypeResponse<PostsByType> Handle(FindPostsByTypeRequest request) {

    IList<FindPostsByTypeResponse.PostDto> posts = _context.Posts
     .Where(x => x.Type == request.Type)
     .Select(x => new FindPostsByTypeResponse.PostDto {
       Id = x.Id,
       Title = x.Title,
       Text = x.Text
     }).ToList();

     return new FindPostsByTypeResponse { Posts = posts };

  }

  public FindPostsByTypeResponse<PostsWithoutTagsDto> Handle(FindPostsByTypeRequest request) {

    IList<FindPostsByTypeResponse.PostsWithoutTagsDto> posts = _context.Posts
     .Where(x => x.Type == request.Type)
     .Select(x => new FindPostsByTypeResponse.PostsWithoutTagsDto {
       Id = x.Id,
       Title = x.Title,
       Text = x.Text
     }).ToList();

     return new FindPostsByTypeResponse { Posts = posts };

  }

  public FindPostsByTypeResponse<PostsWithTagsDto> Handle(FindPostsByTypeRequest request) {
    // Remaining code
  }

}
```

I am not sure this is possible or even the best way to do this ...

Basically I need to "tell" the handler in which format I need the DTOs which are included in the Response.

How can I, or should I, do this?

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED:

Ok, without knowing precisely what you other classes look like, here is an approximate example of what I think would work for you with all the ancillary classes included.  I put this together in Visual Studio and confirmed that it compiles.  In this approach, the ResponseTypeEnum sub class instances determine what type of post to instantiate based on the type mapping via the ConstructItem method on the subclassable enum class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestRequestResponse
{

    #region Generic portions

    /// <summary>
    /// Base request class
    /// </summary>
    public  class       Request {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Base response class
    /// </summary>
    public  class       Response {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic typed namespace for Response/Request support
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="tRequestResponseSet">Request/Response set type parameter (for namespace constraining)</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="tItem">Item type parameter</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="tSourceItem">Source item type parameter</typeparam>
    public  class       RequestResponseSet<tRequestResponseSet, tItem, tSourceItem>
            where       tRequestResponseSet : RequestResponseSet<tRequestResponseSet, tItem, tSourceItem>
            where       tItem               : RequestResponseSet<tRequestResponseSet, tItem, tSourceItem>.Item
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Base item class
        /// </summary>
        public
        abstract    class   Item
        {
            public
            abstract    void    Initialize(tSourceItem sourceItem);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Base type specific subclassable enum class (see https://github.com/TyreeJackson/atomic/blob/master/Atomic.Net/DataTypes/SubclassableEnum.cs for a more generic version)
        /// </summary>
        public
        abstract    class   ResponseTypeEnum
        {
            private
            static      Dictionary
                        <
                            string,
                            ResponseTypeEnum
                        >                       allValues                       = new Dictionary<string,ResponseTypeEnum>();
            private     string                  type;
            private     Func<tItem>             constructItem;
            protected                           ResponseTypeEnum
                                                (
                                                    string      type, 
                                                    Func<tItem> constructItem
                                                )
            {
                this.type           = type;
                this.constructItem  = constructItem;
            }

            public      tItem                   ConstructItem(tSourceItem sourceItem)
            {
                var returnItem  = this.constructItem();
                returnItem.Initialize(sourceItem);
                return returnItem;
            }

            public
            static      ResponseTypeEnum        Select(string type)
            {
                ResponseTypeEnum returnTypeEnum = null;
                return  type == null || !ResponseTypeEnum.allValues.TryGetValue(type, out returnTypeEnum)
                        ?   null
                        :   returnTypeEnum;
            }

            public
            static
            implicit
            operator                            ResponseTypeEnum(string type)
            {
                return ResponseTypeEnum.Select(type);
            }

            public
            static
            implicit
            operator                            string(ResponseTypeEnum typeEnum)
            {
                return typeEnum == null ? null : typeEnum.type;
            }

        }

    }

    #endregion Generic portions

    #region Post specific portions

    /// <summary>
    /// Stored post /entity
    /// </summary>
    public  class       StoredPost
    {
        public  String          Type    { get; set; }
        public  Int32           Id      { get; set; }
        public  String          Title   { get; set; }
        public  String          Text    { get; set; }
        public  List<String>    Tags    { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post specific typed namespace
    /// </summary>
    public  class       PostsSet : RequestResponseSet<PostsSet, PostsSet.Post, StoredPost>
    {

        public  class   Types : ResponseTypeEnum
        {

            public  static      Types   Basic       = new Types("basic",    ()=>new Post());
            public  static      Types   WithTags    = new Types("withTags", ()=>new PostWithTags());

            protected                   Types(string type, Func<Post> createPost) : base(type, createPost) {}
        }

        public  class   Post : Item
        {
            public      Int32   Id      { get; set; }
            public      String  Title   { get; set; }
            public      String  Text    { get; set; }

            public
            override    void    Initialize(StoredPost sourceItem)
            {
                this.Id     = sourceItem.Id;
                this.Title  = sourceItem.Title;
                this.Text   = sourceItem.Text;
            }

        }

        public  class   PostWithTags : Post
        {
            public      List<String>    Tags    { get; set; }

            public
            override    void            Initialize(StoredPost sourceItem)
            {
                base.Initialize(sourceItem);
                this.Tags   = sourceItem.Tags;
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post specific response class
    /// </summary>
    public  class       FindPostsResponse : Response
    {
        public IList<PostsSet.Post> Posts   { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post specific request class
    /// </summary>
    public  class       FindPostsRequest : Request
    {
        public  string  Type    { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post specific context
    /// </summary>
    public  interface   IContext
    {
        IEnumerable<StoredPost> Posts   { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Post specific handler
    /// </summary>
    public  class       FindPostHandler
    {

        private IContext            context;

        public                      FindPostHandler(IContext context)
        {
            this.context    = context;
        }

        public  FindPostsResponse   Handle(FindPostsRequest request)
        {
            var type    = PostsSet.Types.Select(request.Type);

            return
            type == null
            ?   null
            :   new FindPostsResponse()
                {
                    Posts   =
                    this.context.Posts
                    .Where(x => x.Type == request.Type)
                    .Select(x => type.ConstructItem(x))
                    .ToList()
                };
        }

    }

    #endregion Post specific portions

}
```

Comment: Not really. I need something more generic and I need to pass into the request what type do I want. How would you use the dispacther on your example?

Comment: side note... I have never seen such crazy formatting

Comment: The formatting is useful when looking at the methods when they are collapsed using ctrl M-O.  The idea is to look at one method at a time instead of several at once.  Basically first tab stop is the modifier column, second is the type/return type column, third is the property/field/method name and the fourth optional would be the field initialization or property {get; set;}.

Comment: FYI> with a few more type parameters, you could even make the FindPostHandler in this example generic and part of the RequestResponseSet typed namespace (container class).